# How to write unit test for retrofit with mockito in android

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, retrofit2

## I have a simple presenter that I would like to write a Mockito unit test for.

*Here is the code of presenter class in which I call api and get a response and send a response to activity class (view) by use of interface:*

```
class TrendingGifsPresenter(private val iTrendingGif: ITrendingGif, private val iShowError: IShowError) {


fun getTrendingGifs(offSet: Int) {
    val trendingGifs: Call<TrendingGifsModel> = ServiceRegistry.getInstance().getApi().getTrendingGifs("Z23s0syKe5njqYEIt8WjarxhNy9aZFaZ", offSet)

    trendingGifs.enqueue(object : Callback<TrendingGifsModel> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<TrendingGifsModel>?, t: Throwable?) {
            println(t!!.localizedMessage)
            iShowError.showError()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<TrendingGifsModel>?, response: Response<TrendingGifsModel>?) {
            if (response != null && response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null && response.body()!!.meta!!.status==200) {
                iTrendingGif.setTrendingGifs(response.body())
            }
        }
    })

}

fun getLoadMoreTrendingGifs(offSet: Int) {
    val trendingGifs: Call<TrendingGifsModel> = ServiceRegistry.getInstance().getApi().getTrendingGifs("Z23s0syKe5njqYEIt8WjarxhNy9aZFaZ", offSet)

    trendingGifs.enqueue(object : Callback<TrendingGifsModel> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<TrendingGifsModel>?, t: Throwable?) {
            println(t!!.localizedMessage)
            iShowError.showError()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<TrendingGifsModel>?, response: Response<TrendingGifsModel>?) {
            if (response != null && response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null && response.body()!!.meta!!.status == 200) {
                iTrendingGif.loadMoreTrendingGifs(response.body())
            }
        }
    })

}}
```

Comment: I suggest you take a look at https://github.com/adavis/adept-android/blob/retrofit2-testing/app/src/test/java/info/adavis/adeptandroid/books/books/BooksPresenterTest.java

Comment: Can you explain the code? @Raghunandan

Comment: you mock all external dependencies of the presenter class and then mock your response and youuse argument capture to capture values in callback and finally verify the methods were called or not.

Comment: `when`(apiInterface!!.getTrendingGifs(API_KEY, 0, GIF_LOAD_LIMIT)).thenReturn(mockCall)
        val res = Response.success(trendingGifsModel)
        trendingGifsPresenter!!.getTrendingGifs(0)
        verify(mockCall)!!.enqueue(argumentCapture!!.capture());
        argumentCapture!!.getValue().onResponse(null, res);
        Mockito.verify(iTrendingGif!!).setTrendingGifs(trendingGifsModel) I am trying this way and I get this error Method threw 'org.mockito.exceptions.verification.WantedButNotInvoked' exception.

Comment: you pass the apinterface in the constructor of the TrendingGifsPresenter instead of having ServiceRegistry.getInstance(). You need to mock all the external dependencies of the class. In the test case you mock the apiinterface and pass the mock in the constructor